# Navigation / Route Planner with option for maximum vehicle speed

Tags: android, web-apps, osx, navigation

Do you know a navigation software or web app where you can add the maximum speed your vehicle is going to the calculation?

Comment: Don't they all have this feature?

Comment: GMaps hasn't. You can pick your vehicle so the algortihm uses the appropriate roads. But I havent found any option to enter my max speed. If you knoow where I can do that, please let me know.

Comment: "Software or web app": If software, what OS? Any other must-have features? Any budget?

Comment: OS: OS X or Android. Budget: the less the better. Must have: Europe map.